# How can I save a Blend canvas?

Tags: rust

I want to use the image and imageproc crates to draw triangles that blend if there are any overlapping triangles. Currently my code looks like this:

```
use image::{Rgba, RgbaImage};
use imageproc::drawing;
use imageproc::drawing::Blend;
use imageproc::point::Point;

struct Triangle([Point<i32>; 3]);

fn main() {
    let triangle = Triangle([
        Point { x: 0, y: 0 },
        Point { x: 100, y: 400 },
        Point { x: 400, y: 100 },
    ]);
    let mut image = Blend(RgbaImage::new(400, 400));
    drawing::draw_polygon_mut(&mut image, &triangle.0, Rgba([255, 255, 0, 255]));
    drawing::draw_polygon_mut(&mut image, &triangle.0, Rgba([0, 0, 255, 255]));
    image.save("test.png").unwrap();
}
```

This should produce a single white triangle, but there is no save method for Blend canvases. Is there an easy way to save this image?

Answer (score 1):

The actual `ImageBuffer` object is inside of the `Blend` object.

You can extract it via either destructuring or `.0`.

- Destructuring:

```
let Blend(image_buffer) = image;
image_buffer.save("test.png").unwrap();
```

- `.0`:

```
image.0.save("test.png").unwrap();
```